# access file loaded via html <form> using python

Tags: python, html, forms

I have a python script which returns html code which works in a browser.
This is the python code with just the `<form>` part of the `html`:

```
def index():
    return html("   ")


def html(woord):
    return """
<form value ='form' action=http://www.cytosine.nl/~owe4_pg3/Rogier/DreamteamPy/page1.py/fileloader method="post">
    <p>
   <LABEL for="sequence">Sequence: </LABEL>
   <INPUT type="file" name="thefile"><BR>
   <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
    </p>""" + woord+"""
</form>
"""
```

Which is send to the following function in the same python file:

```
def fileloader(req):
    info = req.form
    file = info["thefile"]
    woord = "<br><br>The file has been loaded:<br>{}".format(file)
    return html(woord)
```

This works properly and will show

```
The file has been loaded:
testfile.doc
```

in the browser.

But how can I actually access the file and, for example, print its contents?
I've tried:

```
def fileloader(req):
    info = req.form
    file = open(info["thefile"])
    text = file.read()
    woord = "<br><br>The file has been loaded:<br>{}".format(text)
    return html(woord)
```

But that gives the error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: Field('thefile','testfile.doc')
```

If I remove the `open()` it will give the error

```
AttributeError: read
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
<form value ='form' action=http://www.cytosine.nl/~owe4_pg3/Rogier/DreamteamPy/page1.py/fileloader method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
   <LABEL for="sequence">Sequence: </LABEL>
   <INPUT type="file" name="thefile"><BR>
   <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
    </p>""" + woord+"""
def fileloader(req):
    info = req.form["thefile"].file
    #file = open(info["thefile"].file)
    text = info.read()
    woord = "<br><br>The file has been loaded:<br>{}".format(text)
    return html(woord)
```